# Delete my Ask Ubuntu and Ask Ubuntu Meta account

Tags: support, meta

I want to delete my Ask Ubuntu and Ask Ubuntu meta account, but there is a problem, in the section "Contact us", the following e-mail adress "team%2bmeta.askubuntu@stackexchange.com" and "team%2baskubuntu@stackexchange.com" contains a % symbol, so my Hotmail tell me he can't send the mail.
My User ID is 33572.

Can you delete my account please ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

We have deleted your account for you.